# Check on a list of JSON objects in Ansible

Tags: json, loops, ansible

I have in stdout a list of json objects:

```
[
    {
      "key1": "value1",
      "status": "connected",
      "key2": "value2"
    },
    {
      "key1": "value1",
      "status": "disconnected",
      "key2": "value2"
    },
    ...
]
```

I would loop on this list and check the value of key "status".
If it is "connected" for all objects, set a var to true. If there is at least one object with "status" to "disconnected", set the var to false.

Comment: Ok, so what have you tried thus far and what is the error or bad outcome you're getting? Please don't put that in the comments, rather [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72518445/edit) to include it

Answer (score 1):

use selectattr to check if a value is present:

```
- name: load json
  shell: cat file.json
  register: result

- name: save the Json data to a Variable as a Fact
  set_fact:
    jsondata: "{{ result.stdout | from_json }}"

- name: trap final result
  set_fact:
    status: "{{ value|int == 0 }}"
  vars:
    value: "{{ jsondata | selectattr('status', 'match', 'disconnected') |length}}"

- debug:
    var: status
```

---

`jsondata | selectattr('status', 'match', 'disconnected') |length`  gives the lenght of array containing `disconnected`  so if result is 0, that means all values are `connected`

Comment: I have a stdout like this: "stdout": "{\"connections\":[{\"cid\":\"1234\",\"cname\":\"Hello\",\"interval\":600,\"last-successful\":\"2022-06-07T06:50:09+0000\",\"status\":\"connected\",\"id\":\"sduehf234\"},{\"cid\":\"4567\",\"cname\":\"Hi\",\"interval\":600,\"last-successful\":\"2022-06-07T06:50:09+0000\",\"status\":\"disconnected\",\"id\":\"aoebxs34451\"}]}" .

Comment: But I received the followng error "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: Unable to look up a name or access an attribute in template string ({{ rlr_list.stdout | from_json }}).\nMake sure your variable name does not contain invalid characters like '-': the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'AnsibleUndefined'". The issue is on : jsondata: "{{ rlr_list.stdout | from_json }}"

Comment: could you show your playbook..how you build your file?

Comment: and what is your version of ansible?